# How do I turn off auto date formatting in openoffice writer?

Tags: formatting

Open office inside tables is changing things like the following to dates:

- 6/10
- 9/10

How do I turn this annoying thing off if I/m trying to do scale stuff?

Comment: This question isn't about writing; sending it to Superuser. (You may want to add more information to the question, like the OpenOffice version number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking the cell(s) choosing number format and checking something other than date.
I couldn't replicate the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

Tools > Options > OpenOffice Writer > Table

Uncheck "Number recognition"

Click OK